# How to sort ip address in ascending order

Tags: java, sorting, ip-address

Is there any method to sort this? Or do I just need to split it and use a loop to compare?
Input

```
123.4.245.23
104.244.253.29
1.198.3.93
32.183.93.40
104.30.244.2
104.244.4.1
```

Output

```
1.198.3.93
32.183.93.40
104.30.244.2
104.244.4.1
104.244.253.29
123.4.245.23
```

So far I use HashMap to stored my data. I want sort the value by the  Ip address in ascending order. Seems TreeMap is better choice?

Comment: Splitting it up is the way to go.

Comment: are your IP's String type??

Comment: you can make Comparator and then use Collections.sort using your own Comparator

Comment: Yeah. So I need to convert it to integer first.

Comment: Create a comparator that splits the string and compares each of the 4 parts as ints.  Should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Convert, store in a two D array with original one and converted one without dots. Then sort ascending and pull out originals to match. May be a long way but works ;-)

Comment: Here in [Thilo's Dev-Blog](http://thilosdevblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/15/sorting-ip-addresses-in-java/) is solution. Now work is left with converting your ip type to `InetAddress` Object.

Answer (score 12):

**TLDR**

Don't rewrite the wheel like I tried too, use the `InetAddress` class in a `Comparator`.

**Edit**

A more efficient and accurate way to do it is with the [`InetAddress` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) mentioned above. Credits to [200_success](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1157100/200-success) for code.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.Inet6Address;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class IPSort {
    private static String[] TESTS = {"0:0:0:0:0:0:fff:ffff","::FFFF:222.1.41.90",":8:","::::5:6::8","::::5:6::7","::::5:6::8","123..245.23","1...","..1.","123...23",".1..","123..245.23", "123..245.23", "104.244.253.29", "1.198.3.93", "32.183.93.40", "32.183.93.40", "104.30.244.2", "104.244.4.1","0.0.0.1",":a:","::5:3:4:5:6:78","1::2:3","1::2:3:4","1::5:256.2.3.4","1:1:3000.30.30.30","ae80::217:f2ff:254:7:237:98","::2:3:4:5:6:7","2:3:4:5:6:7","::5:3:4:5:6:7:8","::5:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:0","1::8","1::2:3","1::2:3:4","1::5:256.2.3.4","1:1:3000.30.30.30","ae80::217:f2ff:254.7.237.98","1:2:3:4::5:1.2.3.4","2001:0000:1234:0000:0000:C1C0:ABCD:0876","12345::6:7:8","1::1.2.900.4","fe80::","::ffff:0:0"};
    
    public static class InetAddressComparator implements Comparator<InetAddress> {
        @Override
        public int compare(InetAddress a, InetAddress b) {
            byte[] aOctets = a.getAddress(),
                   bOctets = b.getAddress();
            int len = Math.max(aOctets.length, bOctets.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                byte aOctet = (i >= len - aOctets.length) ?
                    aOctets[i - (len - aOctets.length)] : 0;
                byte bOctet = (i >= len - bOctets.length) ?
                    bOctets[i - (len - bOctets.length)] : 0;
                if (aOctet != bOctet) return (0xff & aOctet) - (0xff & bOctet);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static Optional<InetAddress> toInetAddress(String s) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(InetAddress.getByName(s));
        } catch (UnknownHostException badAddress) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Valid 32-bit addresses");
        Arrays.stream(TESTS)
              .map(IPSort::toInetAddress)
              .filter(Optional::isPresent)
              .map(Optional::get)
              .filter((addr) -> addr instanceof Inet4Address)
              .map(InetAddress::getHostAddress)
              .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("\nValid 128-bit addresses");
        Arrays.stream(TESTS)
              .map(IPSort::toInetAddress)
              .filter(Optional::isPresent)
              .map(Optional::get)
              .filter((addr) -> addr instanceof Inet6Address)
              .map(InetAddress::getHostAddress)
              .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("\nInvalid addresses");
        Arrays.stream(TESTS)
              .filter((s) -> !toInetAddress(s).isPresent())
              .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("\nSorted addresses");
        Arrays.stream(TESTS)
              .map(IPSort::toInetAddress)
              .filter(Optional::isPresent)
              .map(Optional::get)
              .sorted(new InetAddressComparator())
              .map(InetAddress::getHostAddress)
              .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

---

**Original Answer**

In order to sort IPs you first need to know a bit about them. There are two types of IPs; `32 Bit` and `128 Bit`.

**32 Bit** [Source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Ipv4_address.svg)

[image: 32 Bit]

- The `32 bit IP` is split into 4 groups of numbers between `0` and `255`. These groups are seperated via a `.`
- A single group, as shown above, is 8 bits of data. This is the reason the numbers in a group are limited between `0` and `255`.
- For a `32 bit IP` to be formatted correctly it should be `int.int.int.int`. Even if the int is a `0` it must be shown in the IP address. This is different to a `128 bit IP` which may omit `0`s. For example `::5:` which is the same as `0:0:5:0:0:0:0:0`.

**128 Bit** [Source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Ipv6_address_leading_zeros.svg)

[image: 128 Bit]

- The `128 bit IP` is split into 8 groups of numbers between `0` and `FFFF` (which is equivalent to `65535`). Unlike a `32 bit IPs` group, these groups are separated buy a `:`.
- A single group, as show above, is 16 bits of data. This is the reason the numbers in the groups are limited between `0` and `FFFF`.
- To format a `128 bit IP` properly there are several rules you have to follow. `0`s may be omitted from groups and if the remaining groups all are `0` then the groups may also be omitted. The groups have to be separated by a `:`. If you are omitting groups the last group which isn't a `0` has to be followed by a `:`. These rules leave us with a format `int:int:int:int:int:int:int:int`. An example of `0`s and groups being omitted would be `58f:::fff:2:`. This is the same as `58f:0:0:fff:2:0:0:0`.

**Sorting**

Once the IPs have been sorted into their respective groups they can be sorted. To sort an IP you need to use a method called weighting. This is because simply adding or multiplying different groups together wouldn't work. For example take the these two IPs; `192.5.48.198` and `198.48.5.192`. If you add or multiply the values of the groups together you get the same answer. So there is no way to accurately compare them using addition and multiplication. If you use weighting you get something like this.

**32 Bit Weighting**

```
Value of IP = (Group one value * 256^4) + (Group two value * 256^3) +
              (Group three value * 256^2) + (Group four value * 256)
```

**128 Bit Weighting**

```
Value of IP = (Group one value * 65536^8) + (Group two value * 65536^7) +
              (Group three value * 65536^6) + (Group four value * 65536^5) +
              (Group five value * 65536^4) + (Group six value * 65536^3) +
              (Group seven value * 65536^2) + (Group eight value * 65536)
```

**The Code in Java**

As long as the IP is formatted reasonably correctly this code will separate the two kinds of IP and then sort them.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*; //For BigInteger
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class IPSort
{
    String[] tests = {":8:","::::5:6::8","::::5:6::7","::::5:6::8","123..245.23","1...","..1.","123...23",".1..","123..245.23", "123..245.23", "104.244.253.29", "1.198.3.93", "32.183.93.40", "32.183.93.40", "104.30.244.2", "104.244.4.1","0.0.0.1",":a:","::5:3:4:5:6:78","1::2:3","1::2:3:4","1::5:256.2.3.4","1:1:3000.30.30.30","ae80::217:f2ff:254:7:237:98"};
    ArrayList<String> bit32 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> bit128 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> cleanBit32 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> cleanBit128 = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    boolean myMatcher32Bit(String s)
    {
        Pattern patter32Bit = Pattern.compile("^(?=(?:[^.]*\\.){3}[^.]*$)(?=(?:[^:]*:){0}[^:]*$)(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[^a-zA-Z])*$)");
        Matcher matcher32Bit = patter32Bit.matcher(s);
        return matcher32Bit.find();
    }
    
    boolean myMatcher128Bit(String s)
    {
        Pattern patter128Bit = Pattern.compile("^(?=(?:[^.]*\\.){0}[^.]*$)(?=(?:[^:]*:){1,7}[^:]*$)");
        Matcher matcher128Bit = patter128Bit.matcher(s);
        return matcher128Bit.find();
    }
    
    public void sortIntoRespectiveIPTypes()
    {
        for(String s: tests)
        {
            if(myMatcher32Bit(s))
            {
                bit32.add(s);
            }
            else if(myMatcher128Bit(s))
            {
                bit128.add(s);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("32 bit IPs");
        for(String ip: bit32)
        {
            System.out.println("  "+ip);
        }
        
        System.out.println("\n128 bit IPs");
        for(String ip: bit128)
        {
            System.out.println("  "+ip);
        }
        
        int count = 0;
        for(String ip: tests)
        {
            if(myMatcher32Bit(ip)==false && myMatcher128Bit(ip)==false)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        
        if(count != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nDidn't match an IP format");
            for(String ip: tests)
            {
                if(myMatcher32Bit(ip)==false && myMatcher128Bit(ip)==false)
                {
                    System.out.println("  "+ip);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public void sort32BitIPs(ArrayList<String> bit32, ArrayList<String> newBit32)
    {
        ArrayList<BigInteger> bigInt32Bit = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        for(String ip:bit32)
        {
            String[] tempArray = ip.split("\\.");
            int i=0;
            for(String s:tempArray)
            {
                if(s.equals(""))
                {
                    tempArray[i]="0";
                }
                i++;
            }
            bigInt32Bit.add(convert32Bit(tempArray));
        }
        
        Collections.sort(bigInt32Bit);
        
        ArrayList<String> fixFormat = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String ip:bit32)
        {
            String[] fixArray = ip.split("\\.");
            int i=0;
            for(String s:fixArray)
            {
                if(s.equals(""))
                {
                    fixArray[i]="0";
                }
                i++;
            }
            
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 4; i2++) 
            {
                if(i2<3)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if(!fixArray[i2].equals(""))
                        {
                            strBuilder.append(fixArray[i2]+".");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strBuilder.append(".");
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        strBuilder.append("0.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        strBuilder.append(fixArray[i2]);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        strBuilder.append("0");
                    }
                }
            }
            String newString = strBuilder.toString();
            fixFormat.add(newString);
            bit32=fixFormat;
        }
        
        for(BigInteger finalValue:bigInt32Bit)
        {
            for(String ip:bit32)
            {
                String[] tempArray = ip.split("\\.");
                int i=0;
                for(String s:tempArray)
                {
                    if(s.equals(""))
                    {
                        tempArray[i]="0";
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if(finalValue.equals(convert32Bit(tempArray)))
                {
                    if(!newBit32.contains(ip))
                    {
                        String str = bit32.toString();
                        String findStr = ip;
                        int lastIndex = 0;
                        int count = 0;

                        while(lastIndex != -1){

                            lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr,lastIndex);

                            if(lastIndex != -1){
                                count++;
                                lastIndex += findStr.length();
                            }
                        }
                        
                        for(int k = 0; k<count;k++)
                        {
                            newBit32.add(ip);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    BigInteger convert32Bit(String[] array)
    {
        int[] tempArray = new int[array.length];
        ArrayList<BigInteger> tempBigIntList = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        int i = 0;
        for(String s:array)
        {
            int power = 4-i;
            tempArray[i]= Integer.parseInt(s);
            String string = Integer.toString(tempArray[i]);
            BigInteger myBigInt = new BigInteger(string);
            BigInteger num2 = myBigInt.multiply(new BigInteger("256").pow(power));
            tempBigIntList.add(num2);
            i++;
        }
        BigInteger bigInt32Bit = new BigInteger("0");
        for(BigInteger bI:tempBigIntList)
        {
            bigInt32Bit = bigInt32Bit.add(bI);
        }
        return bigInt32Bit;
    }
    
    public void sort128BitIPs(ArrayList<String> bit128,ArrayList<String> newBit128)
    {
        ArrayList<BigInteger> bigInt128Bit = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        for(String ip:bit128)
        {
            String[] tempArray = ip.split(":");
            int i=0;
            for(String s:tempArray)
            {
                if(s.equals(""))
                {
                    tempArray[i]="0";
                }
                i++;
            }
            bigInt128Bit.add(convert128Bit(tempArray));
        }
        
        Collections.sort(bigInt128Bit);
        
        for(BigInteger finalValue:bigInt128Bit)
        {
            for(String ip:bit128)
            {
                String[] tempArray = ip.split(":");
                int i=0;
                for(String s:tempArray)
                {
                    if(s.equals(""))
                    {
                        tempArray[i]="0";
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if(finalValue.equals(convert128Bit(tempArray)))
                {
                    if(!newBit128.contains(ip))
                    {
                        String str = bit128.toString();
                        String findStr = ip;
                        int lastIndex = 0;
                        int count = 0;

                        while(lastIndex != -1){

                            lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr,lastIndex);

                            if(lastIndex != -1){
                                count++;
                                lastIndex += findStr.length();
                            }
                        }
                        
                        for(int k = 0; k<count;k++)
                        {
                            newBit128.add(ip);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    BigInteger convert128Bit(String[] array)
    {
        int[] tempArray = new int[array.length];
        ArrayList<BigInteger> tempBigIntList = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        int i = 0;
        for(String s:array)
        {
            int power = 8-i;
            tempArray[i]= Integer.parseInt(s,16);
            String string = Integer.toString(tempArray[i]);
            BigInteger myBigInt = new BigInteger(string);
            BigInteger num2 = myBigInt.multiply(new BigInteger("65536").pow(power));
            tempBigIntList.add(num2);
            i++;
        }
        BigInteger bigInt128Bit = new BigInteger("0");
        for(BigInteger bI:tempBigIntList)
        {
            bigInt128Bit = bigInt128Bit.add(bI);
        }
        return bigInt128Bit;
    }
    
    public void printInOrder(ArrayList<String> bit32,ArrayList<String> bit128)
    {
        System.out.println("\nSorted IPs");
        
        System.out.println("Sorted 32 bit IPs - Ascending");
        for(String ip: bit32)
        {
            System.out.println("  "+ip);
        }
        
        Collections.reverse(bit32);
        System.out.println("\nSorted 32 bit IPs - Descending");
        for(String ip: bit32)
        {
            System.out.println("  "+ip);
        }
        
        System.out.println("\nSorted 128 bit IPs - Ascending");
        for(String ip: bit128)
        {
            System.out.println("  "+ip);
        }
        
        Collections.reverse(bit128);
        System.out.println("\nSorted 128 bit IPs - Descending");
        for(String ip: bit128)
        {
            System.out.println("  "+ip);
        }
    }
    
    public void run(ArrayList<String> bit32,ArrayList<String> bit128,ArrayList<String> newBit32,ArrayList<String> newBit128)
    {
        sortIntoRespectiveIPTypes();
        sort32BitIPs(bit32,newBit32);
        sort128BitIPs(bit128,newBit128);
        printInOrder(newBit32,newBit128);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        IPSort ipS = new IPSort();
        ipS.run(ipS.bit32,ipS.bit128,ipS.cleanBit32,ipS.cleanBit128);
    }
}
```

*As a note it is possible to use [this class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) to sort IPs but my code does not use it*

*This code also sorts the list into an ascending order, then into a descending order. This is printed out in the command console when the code is run*

**Output**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to implement your own Comparator. See this post: [Sorting IP addresses in Java](http://thilosdevblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/15/sorting-ip-addresses-in-java/)

Copy paste only for you:

```
/**
 * LGPL
 */
public class InetAddressComparator implements Comparator {
    @Override
    public int compare(InetAddress adr1, InetAddress adr2) {
        byte[] ba1 = adr1.getAddress();
        byte[] ba2 = adr2.getAddress();

        // general ordering: ipv4 before ipv6
        if(ba1.length < ba2.length) return -1;
        if(ba1.length > ba2.length) return 1;

        // we have 2 ips of the same type, so we have to compare each byte
        for(int i = 0; i < ba1.length; i++) {
            int b1 = unsignedByteToInt(ba1[i]);
            int b2 = unsignedByteToInt(ba2[i]);
            if(b1 == b2)
                continue;
            if(b1 < b2)
                return -1;
            else
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private int unsignedByteToInt(byte b) {
        return (int) b & 0xFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexWien Could you elaborate as to why it is not a good example?

Comment: Ah I see you were commenting on a forum link that has since been removed.

Comment: Thanks theon,I could not remember why i wrote this., The current link looks good.

Answer (score 3):

For the ip4 adresses you showed you just
need to split it up. then i would convert it to a long value, and sort by that.

```
long value = f3 + f2*256 + f1 * 256^2 + f0 * 256^3
```

where f0 - f3 are the splitted values.

Answer (score 1):

Pad each fragment in `IP` to length `3` and then `sort` e.g. below:

```
    List<String> ipList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ipList.add("123.4.245.23");
    ipList.add("104.244.253.29");
    ipList.add("1.198.3.93");
    ipList.add("32.183.93.40");
    ipList.add("104.30.244.2");
    ipList.add("104.244.4.1");
    Collections.sort(ipList, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            String[] ips1 = o1.split("\\.");
            String updatedIp1 = String.format("%3s.%3s.%3s.%3s",
                                                  ips1[0],ips1[1],ips1[2],ips1[3]);
            String[] ips2 = o2.split("\\.");
            String updatedIp2 = String.format("%3s.%3s.%3s.%3s",
                                                  ips2[0],ips2[1],ips2[2],ips2[3]);
            return updatedIp1.compareTo(updatedIp2);
        }
    });
    //print the sorted IP
    for(String ip: ipList){
        System.out.println(ip);
    }
```

---

It prints:

> 1.198.3.93 
>   32.183.93.40
>   104.30.244.2
>   104.244.4.1
>   104.244.253.29
>   123.4.245.23

Comment: @AlexWien Try is out and let me know. I did the padding just to take care that limitation.

Comment: @AlexWien It took end-to-end 0.016 seconds.

Comment: I have hashMap that stored the ip address as the key. any suggestions? Should I change it to other data structure?

Comment: @John: Ip Address as String, right? What are maintaining as value for the key? Answer depends on your usage.

Comment: I came here for a quick solution, but saw complicated ones. I went with padding. Later, I wanted to check the rest of the answers and found this one. This approach is better, imo. If you're having performance issue, just map the array once and sort the mapped array. For explanation: [Sorting_with_map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class IpSort {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        String[] arr = {"192.168.1.1",  
            "191.122.123.112",  
            "192.161.1.1",  
            "191.122.123.1",  
            "123.24.5.78",  
            "121.24.5.78",  
            "123.24.4.78",  
            "123.2.5.78",  
            "192.1.1.1",  
            "125.45.67.89",  
            "1.1.1.1",  
            "3.4.5.6",  
            "2.2.2.2",  
            "6.6.6.7",  
            "155.155.23.0"};  
        String tmp;  
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)  
        {  
                  for(int j=1;j<arr.length-i;j++)  
                  {  
                      String[] instr1 = arr[j-1].split("\\.");  
                      String[] instr2 = arr[j].split("\\.");  
                           if(Integer.parseInt(instr1[0]) > Integer.parseInt(instr2[0]))  
                           {  
                               tmp=arr[j-1];  
                               arr[j-1]=arr[j];  
                               arr[j]=tmp;  
                           }else if(Integer.parseInt(instr1[0]) == Integer.parseInt(instr2[0])  
                         && Integer.parseInt(instr1[1]) > Integer.parseInt(instr2[1]) )  
                           {  
                                tmp=arr[j-1];  
                                arr[j-1]=arr[j];  
                                arr[j]=tmp;  
                           } else if(Integer.parseInt(instr1[0]) == Integer.parseInt(instr2[0])  
                         && Integer.parseInt(instr1[1]) == Integer.parseInt(instr2[1])  
                         && Integer.parseInt(instr1[2]) > Integer.parseInt(instr2[2]) )  
                           {  
                                tmp=arr[j-1];  
                                arr[j-1]=arr[j];  
                                arr[j]=tmp;  
                           } else if(Integer.parseInt(instr1[0]) == Integer.parseInt(instr2[0])  
                         && Integer.parseInt(instr1[1]) == Integer.parseInt(instr2[1])  
                         && Integer.parseInt(instr1[2]) == Integer.parseInt(instr2[2])  
                         && Integer.parseInt(instr1[3]) > Integer.parseInt(instr2[3]) )  
                           {  
                               tmp=arr[j-1];  
                               arr[j-1]=arr[j];  
                               arr[j]=tmp;  
                           }  
                  }  

        }  
        System.out.println("final sorted list of ips :\n");  
        for(int k=0;k<arr.length;k++){  
            System.out.println(arr[k]);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java8

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;

class Test {
    private static final Comparator<InetAddress> COMPARATOR = Comparator
            .comparing(InetAddress::getAddress,
                    Comparator.comparingInt((byte[] b) -> b.length)
                    .thenComparing(b -> new BigInteger(1, b)));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] addresses = {
                "123.4.245.23",
                "104.244.253.29",
                "1.198.3.93",
                "32.183.93.40",
                "104.30.244.2",
                "104.244.4.1"
        };

        for (final String address : sort(addresses)) {
            System.out.println(address);
        }
    }

    public static String[] sort(final String[] addresses) {
        return Arrays.stream(addresses)
                .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(toInetAddress(s), s))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey, Comparator.nullsLast(COMPARATOR)))
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    private static InetAddress toInetAddress(final String address) {
        try {
            return InetAddress.getByName(address);
        } catch (final UnknownHostException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1.198.3.93
32.183.93.40
104.30.244.2
104.244.4.1
104.244.253.29
123.4.245.23
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this plain logic:

Ip Address: 
    [10.1.1.2, 10.22.33.11, 10.12.23.12]

1) Fill in the IP to complete 12 digits format with prefix 0:
like
    [010.001.001.002, 010.022.033.011, 010.012.023,012]

2) Remove "."s to make it complete string of digits:
    [010001001002, 010022033011, 010012023012]

3) Apply Sort
    [010001001002, 010012023012, 010022033011]

4) Retain dots after every 3 digits:
    [010.001.001.002, 010.012.023.012, 010.022.033.011]

5) Remove prefix 0's
    [10.1.1.2, 10.12.23.12, 10.22.33.11]

6) Sorted!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SortIP
{

    public static String getFormattedIP(String ip)
    {
        String arg[] = new String[4];
        arg = (ip).split("\\.");

        int i=0;
        while(i<=3)
        {
            if(arg[i].length()==1)
            {
                arg[i]="00"+arg[i];
            }
            else if(arg[i].length()==2)
            {
                arg[i]="0"+arg[i];
            }

            i++;
        }

        return arg[0]+arg[1]+arg[2]+arg[3];
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> sortedList(Object[] obj,String order)
    {
        if(order.equalsIgnoreCase("Ascending"))
        {
            Arrays.sort(obj, new Comparator() {
                public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                    return ((Map.Entry<Integer, Long>) o1).getValue()
                               .compareTo(((Map.Entry<Integer, Long>) o2).getValue());
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Arrays.sort(obj, new Comparator() {
                public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                    return ((Map.Entry<Integer, Long>) o2).getValue()
                               .compareTo(((Map.Entry<Integer, Long>) o1).getValue());
                }
            });
        }

        int counter=0;
        ArrayList<Integer> key = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //int key[] = new int[ipRange.size()];

        for (Object e : obj) {
            key.add(((Map.Entry<Integer, Long>) e).getKey());
            //key[counter++]=((Map.Entry<Integer, Long>) e).getKey();

            System.out.println(((Map.Entry<Integer, Long>) e).getKey() + " : " + ((Map.Entry<Integer, Long>) e).getValue());
        }

        return key;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Map<Integer,String> ipRange= new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
        Map<Integer,Long> formatedIpRange= new TreeMap<Integer,Long>();

        ipRange.put(1, "10.1.4.100");
        ipRange.put(2, "1.10.400.10");
        ipRange.put(3, "196.0.14.15");
        ipRange.put(4, "196.70.5.1");
        ipRange.put(5, "196.70.7.3");
        ipRange.put(6, "153.70.7.0");

        for(int j=1;j<=ipRange.size();j++)
        {
            formatedIpRange.put(j, Long.parseLong(getFormattedIP(ipRange.get(j))));
        }

        Object[] a = formatedIpRange.entrySet().toArray();

        ArrayList<Integer> key = sortedList(a,"descending");

        System.out.println("ordered list ");

        for (Integer integer : key) 
        {
            System.out.println(ipRange.get(integer));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
@Override
public int compare(Object adr1, Object adr2) {
    try
    {
        if(adr1 == null || adr1.toString().isEmpty()) return -1;
        if(adr2 == null || adr2.toString().isEmpty()) return 1;
        String[] ba1 = adr1.toString().split( "\\." );
        String[] ba2 = adr2.toString().split( "\\." );

        for ( int i = 0; i < ba1.length; i++ )
        {
            int b1 = Integer.parseInt( ba1[ i ] );
            int b2 = Integer.parseInt( ba2[ i ] );

            if (b1 == b2)
                continue;
            if (b1 < b2)
                return -1;
            else
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation in Perl, but it demonstrates the need to precompute the splits or factorings instead of computing them again and again for each comparison.  I haven't tested it on mixed ipv4 & ipv6 but I think it should work.  I just used the example.  It seems like precomputing split values is the winner, then comparing the quads separately, instead of exponentiating and adding them all up.

```
2022-11-02 11:58:42 Wed $ cat | /tmp/foo.pl 
123.4.245.23
104.244.253.29
1.198.3.93
32.183.93.40
104.30.244.2
104.244.4.1
Benchmark: timing 10000 iterations of factor_each_time, factor_precompute, split_each_time, split_precompute...
factor_each_time:  3 wallclock secs ( 2.94 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.94 CPU) @ 3401.36/s (n=10000)
factor_precompute:  1 wallclock secs ( 1.03 usr +  0.00 sys =  1.03 CPU) @ 9708.74/s (n=10000)
split_each_time:  3 wallclock secs ( 3.01 usr +  0.00 sys =  3.01 CPU) @ 3322.26/s (n=10000)
split_precompute:  1 wallclock secs ( 1.00 usr +  0.00 sys =  1.00 CPU) @ 10000.00/s (n=10000)
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use English '-no_match_vars';

use Regexp::Common;
use Benchmark qw(:all);
#use YAML;

my @lines = <STDIN>;
chomp $_ for @lines;

timethese( 10000, {
    split_each_time => sub {
        my @sorted = sort ip_each_time_split_sorter @lines;
        #warn "split_each_time:\n".Dump(\@sorted);
    },
    split_precompute => sub {
        my @sorted =
            map $_->{num},
            sort ip_precompute_split_sorter
            map split_vals($_),
            @lines
            ;
        #warn "split_precompute:\n".Dump(\@sorted);
    },
    factor_each_time => sub {
        my @sorted = sort ip_each_time_factor_sorter @lines;
        #warn "factor_each_time:\n".Dump(\@sorted);
    },
    factor_precompute => sub {
        my @sorted =
            map $_->{num},
            sort ip_precompute_factor_sorter
            map factor_vals($_),
            @lines
            ;
        #warn "factor_precompute:\n".Dump(\@sorted);
    },
} );

sub ip_each_time_factor_sorter {
    our ($a, $b);
    my $a_factor = factor_vals($a);
    my $b_factor = factor_vals($b);
    return -1 if exists $a_factor->{ipv4} && exists $b_factor->{ipv6};
    return  1 if exists $a_factor->{ipv6} && exists $b_factor->{ipv4};
    return $a_factor->{val} <=> $b_factor->{val};
}

sub ip_precompute_factor_sorter {
    our ($a, $b);
    return -1 if exists $a->{ipv4} && exists $b->{ipv6};
    return  1 if exists $a->{ipv6} && exists $b->{ipv4};
    return $a->{val} <=> $b->{val};
}

sub factor_vals {
    my ($ip) = @_;
    my $xform;
    if ($ip =~ m{ \A $RE{net}{IPv4}{-keep} \z }mxs) {
        $xform = {
            ipv4 => 1,
            num  => $1,
            val  => (
                ($2 || 0) * 256 ** 4
            +   ($3 || 0) * 256 ** 3
            +   ($4 || 0) * 256 ** 2
            +   ($5 || 0) * 256 ** 1
            ),
        };
    }
    elsif ($ip =~ m{ \A $RE{net}{IPv6}{-keep} \z }mxs) {
        $xform = {
            ipv6 => 1,
            num  => $1,
            val  => (
                ($2 || 0) * 65536 ** 8
            +   ($3 || 0) * 65536 ** 7
            +   ($4 || 0) * 65536 ** 6
            +   ($5 || 0) * 65536 ** 5
            +   ($6 || 0) * 65536 ** 4
            +   ($7 || 0) * 65536 ** 3
            +   ($8 || 0) * 65536 ** 2
            +   ($9 || 0) * 65536 ** 1
            ),
        };
    }
    else {
        warn "skipping bad entry: $_\n";
    }
    return $xform;
}


sub split_vals {
    my ($ip) = @_;
    my $xform;
    if ($ip =~ m{ \A $RE{net}{IPv4}{-keep} \z }mxs) {
        $xform = {
            ipv4 => 1,
            num  => $1,
            vals => [
                $2 || 0,
                $3 || 0,
                $4 || 0,
                $5 || 0,
            ],
        };
    }
    elsif ($ip =~ m{ \A $RE{net}{IPv6}{-keep} \z }mxs) {
        $xform = {
            ipv6 => 1,
            num  => $1,
            vals => [
                $2 || 0,
                $3 || 0,
                $4 || 0,
                $5 || 0,
                $6 || 0,
                $7 || 0,
                $8 || 0,
                $9 || 0,
            ],
        };
    }
    else {
        warn "skipping bad entry: $_\n";
    }
    return $xform;
}

sub ip_precompute_split_sorter {
    our ($a, $b);
    return -1 if exists $a->{ipv4} && exists $b->{ipv6};
    return  1 if exists $a->{ipv6} && exists $b->{ipv4};
    my $a_vals = $a->{vals};
    my $b_vals = $b->{vals};
    for my $i (0..$#{$a_vals}) {
        my $sortval = $a_vals->[$i] <=> $b_vals->[$i];
        return $sortval if $sortval != 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

sub ip_each_time_split_sorter {
    our ($a, $b);
    my $a_split = split_vals($a);
    my $b_split = split_vals($b);
    return -1 if exists $a_split->{ipv4} && exists $b_split->{ipv6};
    return  1 if exists $a_split->{ipv6} && exists $b_split->{ipv4};
    my $a_vals = $a_split->{vals};
    my $b_vals = $b_split->{vals};
    for my $i (0..$#{$a_vals}) {
        my $sortval = $a_vals->[$i] <=> $b_vals->[$i];
        return $sortval if $sortval != 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```