# Convert Integer to IP address

Tags: java, string, integer

I've got two ip addresses representing by `String`.

```
String first = "192.168.0.1";
String second = "192.168.0.5";
```

I need to sort it out like:

```
192.168.0.5
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.2
```

Here is my code so far:

```
 private static void method(String first, String second){
        String tempFirst = first.replace(".", "");
        String tempSecond = second.replace(".", "");
        int ipFirst = Integer.valueOf(tempFirst);
        int ipSecond = Integer.valueOf(tempSecond);

        while (ipSecond > ipFirst){
            System.out.println(ipSecond);
            ipSecond--;
        }
    }
```

I need to convert output from these method:

```
19216805
19216804
19216803
19216802
```

to:

```
192.168.0.5
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.2
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: Would 192.168.10.1 > 192.168.9.1

Comment: Yours may be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Myself, I would create my own `public class IpAddress implements Comparable<IpAddress>` class, one that holds 4 ints, and that implements compareTo in an appropriate way.

Comment: Just convert it to a 32bit number, sort, then convert back.

Comment: I would split the string on ".", rather than replace. Convert each element to integers. Then multiply the first element by 1 billion, the second element by a million, and the third by 1000, then add the 4 together. These can then be safely sorted.

Comment: My bad, I misread the question, I'll leave the [previous dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13756235/5515060) as a link though. *Sort* may be the wrong use of word. What you probably meant was: *Print all IP addresses between two given*, or something..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Does `19216802` mean `192.168.0.2` or `192.16.80.2`?

An IP address can just be thought of as an unsigned 32bit number, so your `192.168.0.2` can be seen as `192 * 2 ^ 24 + 168 * 2 ^ 16 + 0 ^ 8 + 2` = `3232235522`

What you really want to do is convert it to a 32bit number, sort, then convert back.

Comment: I think they get string first with"."

Comment: mean 192.168.0.2

Comment: @Maxqueue he's asking to convert `19216802` to `192.168.0.2`, you just cannot do that.

Comment: @Bib he/she starts with String first = "192.168.0.1";
String second = "192.168.0.5";

Comment: @Maxqueue please read his question, he's asking to convert 19216802 to 192.168.0.2. He's looking at this the wrong way.

Comment: @Bib That is after the method where he/she String tempFirst = first.replace(".", "");
        String tempSecond = second.replace(".", ""); You should reread post

Comment: @IMABOT you have no way of knowing if it is that. Convert it to a 32bit number, sort, then convert back.

Comment: @Maxqueue `I need to convert output from these method:19216805... to 192.168.0.5` He need to convert to 32bit, just as the link says.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
private static void ipAddress(String first, String second) throws UnknownHostException {
    byte[] bytesFirst = InetAddress.getByName(first).getAddress();
    byte[] bytesSecond = InetAddress.getByName(second).getAddress();
    int fIP = new BigInteger(1, bytesFirst).intValue();
    int sIP = new BigInteger(1, bytesSecond).intValue();

    while (sIP > fIP){
        int ip  = sIP ;
        String ipStr =
                String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d",
                        (ip >> 24 & 0xff),
                        (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
                        (ip >> 8 & 0xff),
                        (ip & 0xff));
        System.out.println(ipStr);
        sIP--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! A brief explanation of why this works would be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you wish to achieve this is a bad way of doing it.
My personal solution would be implement a class for Ip Addresses:

```java
public class IpAddress implements Comparable<IpAddress> {
        public int A, B, C, D; // A.B.C.D (A,B,C,D are all 8 bit numbers)

        public IpAddress(String Ip) {
            this.A = Integer.valueOf(Ip.split("\\.")[0]);
            this.B = Integer.valueOf(Ip.split("\\.")[1]);
            this.C = Integer.valueOf(Ip.split("\\.")[2]);
            this.D = Integer.valueOf(Ip.split("\\.")[3]);
        }

        public int compareTo(IpAddress other) {
            return (this.A - other.A) * 16581375 + (this.B - other.B) * 65025 + (this.C - other.C) * 255 + (this.D - other.D);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return this.A + "." + this.B + "." + this.C + "." + this.D;
        }

        public void decrement() {
            this.D--;
            if (this.D < 0) {
                this.D = 255;
                this.C--;
                if (this.C < 0) {
                this.C = 255;
                    this.B--;
                    if (this.B < 0) {
                        this.B = 255;
                        this.A--;
                        if (this.A < 0)
                            this.A = 255;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean isGreaterThan(IpAddress other) {
            return (this.compareTo(other) > 0);
        }
  }
```

And for your method do:

```
private static void method(String first, String second){
    IpAddress ipFirst = new IpAddress(first);
    IpAddress ipSecond = new IpAddress(second);

    while (ipSecond.isGreaterThan(ipFirst)){
        System.out.println(ipSecond.toString());
        ipSecond.decrement();
    }
}
```